# meaning of 'CG' in SIOCGIF* in netdevice(7)?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, semantics

Linux [netdevice(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html) interface introduces a number of `SIOCGIF*` constants, for example, `SIOCGIFNAME`.

I suppose the latter reads as "socket i/o ?? interface name", where `??` stands for "CG".

So what is "CG" then? Shall be something simple, but I'm a little stuck here. ( And I'm in a habit of knowing of what my identifiers mean, hence the question )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably **S**ocket **I**/**O** **C**ontrol - **G**et **I**nter**F**ace **NAME**.

It seems obvious that `ioctl` stands for "I/O Control" (but if not then just consider that IOC stands for **IOC**TL)

We can see the `TIOC` prefix used on [some older **T**erminal I/O Controls](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html). T for Terminal and S for Socket - makes sense.

You can also notice the Get functions have G and the Set functions have S.

And IFNAME seems clear enough.

Comment: Looks very reasonable to me, and I'm going to accept the answer unless here comes someone with historical or inside knowledge and disproves it :)